# How can I change the overlay color for each image?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm using FancyBox 2 and I would like to customize the overlay color; I would like this color to match the parent `div` that is clicked.

For example:

```
<div style="background-color:#000"><a class="fancybox"...><img ...></div>
<div style="background-color:#111"><a class="fancybox"...><img ...></div>
```

### Fancybox Code

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox( {
    padding:0,
    helpers : {
        overlay : { 
            css : { 'background-color' :  **PARENT'S COLOR** }
        }
    }
});
```

How do I automatically set the correct color in the code above?

Comment: I think this can be helpful to you http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: EmCo - the issue  is"this" in Fancybox refers to itself, not the effected HTML, so finding the parent is rather convoluted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to get the parent's color on the fly using the `beforeShow` callback and apply it directly to the `.fancybox-overlay` selector like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeShow: function() {
        var parentColor = $(this.element).parent().css('backgroundColor');
        $(".fancybox-overlay").css({
            "backgroundColor": parentColor,
            "backgroundImage": 'none' // optional if you prefer a solid color
        });
    }
});​
```

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6KgFY/)**